# Making z-index of inner links only higher than parent container

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm wondering if something like that would be possible:

```
<div class="arrow-left" style="z-index:2; position: fixed; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>
<div class="meta" style="z-index:1; position: relative;">
    <div class="description">description <a href="link" style="z-index:3; position: relative;">link</a> description</div>
</div>
```

I want `z-index: 3;` link to be above `arrow-left` but `description` below it. Is this achievable with above HTML structure?

Comment: do you want output like this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/krish/fV55N/)

Comment: @krish Yes. Let's assume that arrow-left and arrow-right have `position: fixed;` and `height: 100%; width: 100%;`. I don't want them to cover links but I want them to cover description text.

Comment: I'd say position: absolute on you child element...

Comment: if you dont wanna show text just use text-indent: -9999px; ???

Comment: btw plz add a jsfiddle to show your problem

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: relative;` with `z-index`

Comment: I'm using `position: relative;` obviously. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Full CSS and HTML doesn't matter here. I'm asking about general idea. Is it possible to make nested link display like it was above arrow divs? I guess there is no such option because z-index works only with containers on the same level but maybe I'm mistaken. My only idea is to completely remove `z-index` for meta and its inner divs will perhaps interact with arrows (so it's no longer z-index interaction on the same level).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is logically wrong !

just put the (.arrow-left) inside the (.meta) and it will work.

```
<div class="meta" style="z-index:1; position: relative;">
<div class="arrow-left" style="z-index:2; position: fixed; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>
<div class="description">description <a href="link" style="z-index:3; position: relative;">link</a> description</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would do that long ago if it was so simple. That's not what I'm looking for. What if I have 2 meta containers and I can have only 1 arrow? It won't work.

Comment: OK. is it OK if you disabled all texts without using .arrow-left cover?, because you can disable divs and spans... but allowing only anchors.

Answer (score 0):

Validated use of this method is following

```
<div class="hold" style="z-index:0; position:relative"><!--Outdiv set relative and z-index to 0 here -->
   <div class="arrow-left" style="z-index:2; position: fixed; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>
   <div class="meta" style="z-index:1; position: relative;">
       <div class="description">description <a href="link" style="z-index:3; position: relative;">link</a> description
   </div>
</div>
```

This way you make a ground 0 for your index by setting your outer div as relative and then give it as your main floor like z-index 0 this way you avoid other faults later on according to z-index